# The "i" looks strange in h3 headers

Tags: bug, design

The letter "i" in h3 headers looks odd. Tested in Windows 7, Chrome, IE. For example:

#### Single responsibility principle

Looks like this:

[image]

Basically it looks like capital "I", and it's weird. I don't remember seeing it like this on OSX. h2 and h1 headers are fine.

Can something be done about this?

Comment: dito, reproduced on Chrome for Linux