# Modify the h3 font size

Tags: feature-request, design

Lowercase `i`s look similar to lowercase `l`s in `<h3>` elements (which use the `"Open Sans"` font at size `17px` and weight `700` (bold)) when viewed at 100% zoom in Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Edge on my Windows 7 and Windows 10 machines (but not in Safari or Chrome on my iPhone, or in IE on my old Windows Phone).

#### this is a prime illustrative example

[image: example at 17px]

This legibility issue was mentioned in bug reports from 2015:

- [The "i" looks strange in h3 headers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6349/the-i-looks-strange-in-h3-headers)
- [Certain characters formatted with ### seem messed up under 100% zoom](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6216/certain-characters-formatted-with-seem-messed-up-under-100-zoom)

I don't know that it qualifies as a bug, especially since its appearance seems to vary by machine, but I'm asking for it to be changed.

The legibility would be improved by using a font size of 16px instead of 17px for `<h3>` elements. It would still be larger and bolder than regular text.

Here's a screenshot of the example above modified to use a font-size of 16px:

[image: resized to 16px]

Comment: Yet they describe the exact same issue. FWIW there also has been another bugreport on this that has also been closed as a duplicate ..

Comment: @Vogel612, Yes, I linked to both of them in the body of this request.

Comment: @Thriggle So what makes this *not* a duplicate of either of them?

Comment: @EBrown because it might not be a bug at all. There are no answers to either of those bug reports from 2015, and the comments on one of the bug reports indicate that some people cannot duplicate it. Rather than debate about whether the problem is a bug or not, I'm proposing a change to the H3 font size.

Comment: @Thriggle I don't see how there being no answers, and a handful of people saying they aren't affected make it not a bug. Just because I don't have the common cold, doesn't mean it's not a bug. Also, you may want to test this on more than one device, OS and browser, to check if it does actually fix the issue, and then _post it as an answer_ to the open bug report.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I considered posting this as an answer to Jamal's report; I asked whether I should have done that in the 2nd Monitor but didn't get much encouragement along those lines.